# The complexity of proving the theorem in a particular state and in general

Tags: proof-explanation, alternative-proof

Is it possible to give an example of a theorem that is difficult to prove in a particular case, but easy to prove in general because of the symmetry and order of the theorem?

Comment: I suppose it's easier to prove that $e^x=1+x+(x^2/2)+(x^3/6)+\cdots$ than to prove $\sqrt{e}=1+(1/2)+(1/8)+(1/48)+\cdots$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  If possible, examples are from analysis, functional analysis and topology, which are more familiar to me

Comment: Please don't change the problem after other users have invested time & energy into working on it. If you discover you have left out some important conditions in a question, it's better to gracefully accept the answers users have provided, and then post a new question with everything you left out the first time (and with links between the old and new questions). Anyway, I'm done here, as there's no guarantee you won't move the goalposts again. (And isn't Taylor series analysis?)

Comment: @GerryMyerson you are right,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would not describe the direct proofs of
   [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) as difficult, but that theorem is an [immediate consequence of Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_little_theorem#Proofs_using_group_theory) that the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group.

   Of course that short conceptual proof isn't free. It depends on   developing the abstract concept of a group.
2. Hadamard and de la Vallée Poussin first proved the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) using analytic number theory.  Erdős and Selberg's subsequent "elementary proof" is arguably more complex.
3. Allen R. Bernstein and Abraham Robinson used nonstandard analysis to prove that [polynomially compact operators have an invariant subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace_problem). Halmos then rewrote their proof using only standard constructions.
4. [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) guarantees the existence of invariants in physical systems that result from symmetries.

Comment: If possible, examples are from analysis, functional analysis and topology, which are more familiar to me

Comment: very impressive